# Data type issue with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have read in a CSV file into a pandas dataframe and am trying to run some analyses on the data. However I I'm having problems with the 'items' column. It looks like that particular column has been read in as a different data type to the other columns. When I try to change the datatype using astype I get the error "'function' object has no attribute 'astype'". Any idea why this particular column is being read in as a different datatype?

```
data = pd.read_csv("/Volumes/Toshiba/GPRD/general-practice-prescribing-data/T201605PDPI+BNFT.csv")

print(data.head(10))
print(type(data.quantity))
print(type(data.items))
print(type(data.practice))
print(type(data.bnf_code))
print(type(data.bnf_name))
print(type(data.nic))
print(type(data.act_cost))

practice  bnf_code  bnf_name  items     nic  act_cost  quantity
0      5668      8092       592      2   44.10     40.84       189
1      1596     17512     16983      2    1.64      1.64        35
2      1596     25587     16124      1    1.26      1.28        42
3      1596     12551      1282      2    0.86      1.02        42
4      1596     18938     10575      1    1.85      1.82        56
5      1596      8777     21507      1    3.31      3.18        56
6      1596      9369     12008      1   63.15     58.56        56
7      1596     27926     17643      2  158.66    147.07        56
8      1596     26148     10230      1    0.35      0.44        14
9      1596      9148      3381      1    0.26      0.35         7
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'method'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Try using `data['items']` instead. `data.items()` is a method of a `DataFrame` (as show in your output).

Comment: Thank you! that worked perfectly!

Comment: As Evert stated data['items'] will work.  Using the dot syntax for accessing columns is a shortcut and will not always work.   Such cases, are special words that are the names of dataframe methods or attributes, names with spaces and etc...

Answer (score 0):

`df.items()` is a [method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.items.html) in pandas, please use `type(df["col_name"])`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"items":["1","3"]})

type(df.items)
Out[184]:
method
In [185]:
type(df["items"])
Out[185]:
pandas.core.series.Series
```